# real time data web page

Tags: html, real-time, plc

I am new to programming and am working on pushing real time data from a PLC to a web page either by deploying HTML 5 on the WAGO or a Modbus driver wrapper. I honestly have tried to research but don't know where to start. it will be a closed private network with little to no influence from the outside web. I am simply looking to display a single piece of live information for proof of concept. basically I'm trying to custom design a Groov program.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, such broad questions are considered off-topic.

Comment: You might have better luck on Reddit with such a broad question unless you have specific question to ask I'm afraid. Edit: Look into https://www.firebase.com/ you may not need all of that, you could do with https://www.parse.com/. Not sure on your requirements. Might be enough to get your started, Michael.

Comment: at this point the project is to program a simple web app from scratch that will display a single piece of live information taken from a life support system PLC via a private network and no outside server access using HTML5. it may not be as vague of a question as it is so simple. I cannot use any apps already made so basically i am making a program as a proof of concept to web developed on.

Comment: 50 register 200 input 160 output got 120 ms delay. its not real time! Try Can,PROFI etc. Modbus is slow !

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using OPC. Kepware & SoftwareToolbox are just 2 of many vendors that offer tools to help you get your data the way you want it.
There is an existing tool to do what you want, but I am under the impression you have to write one from scratch. The existing tool is http://www.softwaretoolbox.com/cogentdatahub/ if you are interested in looking at it for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately you can not push data to a browser.
The Internet would become an even greater mess if you could.
To solve this, have your webpage contain a timer, written in JavaScript.
Every say 1 sec. it does an AJAX request (e.g. use jQuery implementation) to the server, which then delivers (almost) realtime data.
The webpage then displays that in some DOM element, e.g. an empty DIV.
So it's the browser polling your server.

@BlueDog

The data is "almost" realtime because sampling once a second gives a delay of at least one second. In the ideal case, as soon as data changes, it would be pushed to the browser. Unfortunately the browser has no way of knowing that anything changed, so the best it can do is frequently "ask" for updates (polling).

How much the delay is depends on your poll frequency. If it's once per second one has to add the delays for transmission of the page request and the reply of the server. The transmission time depends on your network (which may be the Internet with all uncertainty involved). If the backbones involved have enough capacity I expect overall delay to be between 1 and 1.5 seconds. With a dedicated network and even more frequent polling, I expect that 0.5 seconds should be possible. These are however estimated averages. If I request a page over the Internet and my provider (again) has a problem, it may be hours before I receive what I want. Also things like virus scanners and OS updates may spoil your game.

So, practically: with a good broadband connection, a stable browser and the right process priorities it should be possible to get below 1 second overall delay (incl. poll time interval) for 95% of the time. Be prepared to reboot the client every few days. Most browsers leak memory and most OS'es do so too.

Comment: you can push to a browser if your browser has an open stream.  Websockets is much more efficient because it does push to the browser.  AJAX is inefficient in that you may be requesting far too often and getting the same data back causing the internet to be a mess.

Comment: hi Jacques, why is it 'almost' realt time data and how 'almost do you think it is ? 20% or 90% almost real time ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to interface with PLC using python and modbusTCP and an Raspberry pi as the webserver. Python is a quick and easy to learn language. Websockets are the HTML5 component best used for realtime data. 
simple connect code (after you install everything):

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient
from time import sleep
client = ModbusClient('ip_address_of_modbus_IO')
if(client.connect()):
    print(client.read_discrete_inputs(200,1).bits[0])
    client.write_coil(0,True)
    sleep(100)
    client.write_coil(2,True)
```

found here:

http://simplyautomationized.blogspot.com/2013/09/home-automation-project-2-rpi-light.html

Can create a websocket broadcast server using an example here:

http://simplyautomationized.blogspot.com/2015/09/raspberry-pi-create-websocket-api.html

Comment: so, do you read 200 PLC tags every 100ms ? do you open & close socket connection every 100ms ?

Comment: this code prints the value of a single bit in a input byte at address 200
writes 1 to output coil 0
waits 100ms 
and writes 1 to output coil 2

the socket is left open until you call client.close()